# Finding boundary point for normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose that $P(x \, | \, \omega_i) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \sigma^2)$ for $i = 1, 2$ and that $P(\omega_1) = P(\omega_2) = 1/2$. I'm trying to find a value $x$ such that $P(\omega_1 \, | \, x) = P(\omega_2 \, | \, x) = 1/2$. We assume that $\mu_2 \geq \mu_1$.

My intuition is telling me that since both random variables have the same variance, the value $x$ that I'm seeking is simply $(\mu_2 + \mu_1)/2$. However, I'm having a hard time showing this.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Considering the standard normal PDF $\varphi$, you are looking for $x$ such that $P(\omega_1\mid x)=P(\omega_2\mid x)$, that is, such that $P(\omega_1,x)=P(\omega_2,x)$, that is, since $P(\omega_1)=P(\omega_2)$, such that  $P(x\mid\omega_1)=P(x\mid\omega_2)$, that is, such that $\varphi(x-\mu_1)=\varphi(x-\mu_2)$, that is, since $\varphi$ is even, such that $x-\mu_1=-(x-\mu_2)$, that is, $$x=\tfrac12(\mu_1+\mu_2).$$

Comment: More generally, assuming densities for two general distributions exist, $$\frac {P(\omega_1|x)}{P(\omega_2|x)}=\frac {P(\omega_1)}{P(\omega_2)}\frac {P(x|\omega_1)}{P(x|\omega_2)}$$ In your case, the prior odds are 1:1, you are seeking 1:1 posterior odds and hence you are simply looking for an intersection of pdfs - which is in the middle of their means. You can use this more generally.